# What should be the type for an object method returning this in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have an object like below:

```
const console = {
  write(text: string) {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  },
  writeLine(text: string) {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  }
};
```

What should be the return type of **write** and **writeLine** methods here?

I know that we can define an interface and set that as the return type but is there any other way to set the type that refers to the object?

Comment: you dont need to declare explicitly return type. TS is able to infer it. If you want you can use `write(text: string): typeof this`

Comment: @captain-yossarian you are right, but ESLint is showing that as a warning. Though we can turn that rule off but want to know if there is any other explicit way to define the return type in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define return type explicitly in this way:

```js
const _console = {
  write(text: string): typeof this {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  },
  writeLine(text: string): typeof this {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA%20qSIA2BTGBeGBvAUDGAdwCcBLKVACgoA8oAuGaMsAcwEpGoBPAB1RAAzGFAAWpCDnwEYAegBUMZCFalgMebOkFiqKAFdiYEeIgBuaQF8ANNJLlUAGVJgqtBkygsOXPgOFiElIycorKquqa2jC6BkYmEhYElriWFkA)

Or you can define your `console` as a class and just use `this`:

```js
class Console {
  write(text: string): this {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  }
  writeLine(text: string): this {
    /* logic */
    return this;
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7C8QFNoG8BQ1oHcAnASwBc0AKcgD1IC5oJSTEBzASgdIAtiYc8eAPQAqaCHitiwaCKG5BhNKQCuhRNB58A3AoC%20ComTQAZYoko16jZuY5de-BcLESpMuc%20hLV6zY908Az1dIA)

I hope it makes ESLint happy :D

Comment: I can't use a `class` in my code. Like you suggested we can use `typeof` type operator. Eg. `typeof console` Thank you.